# Dual graphical cards switching

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a HP ENVY dv6-7392ef, and two graphical cards are on my station a Geforce GT635 and an Intel HDGraphics 4000.

I tried to play 'Arma 3' on my pc and gotten curious because the graphics were too slow. So I deduced the game must be using the Intel HD Graphics 4000 instead of the other. What makes the PC chose which graphical card to use? And how do I select the adequat card for a certain program or application?

Comment: The GeForce GT635 is what the laptop is using. The Intel HD 4000 only "helps" with graphics and is the primary only when there isn't another dedicated card installed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not automatically switching then you might have to manually switch it before starting your game.

I would recommend reading through the documentation.

You can Google "hp graphics switching nvidia" or check out these links:

- http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03519217&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en
- http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/How-to-switch-VGA-card-from-Intel-to-NVIDIA/td-p/2872925

Answer (score 0):

Open Nvidia control panel -> click on desktop menu on the top-> click on "Add "Run with graphic processor menu to Context Menu"" if it is not already checked.

Then to open the game, right click and select "Run with graphic processor menu to Context Menu".

Hopefully it will force the laptop to use Nvidia gpu to run the game.